# How do I select <dei:DocumentType from XBRL using Cheerio (or

Tags: parsing, xbrl, cheerio

I'm trying to get the text (in this case it's '10-Q') of an entry from XBRL using cheerio.js with nodejs.  The line is below:

```
<dei:DocumentType contextRef="D2013Q3YTD" id="Fact-DB2A50C2A485F9CC21D51934C6E61D42">10-Q</dei:DocumentType>
```

**I've tried:**

```
$('dei:DocumentType').text
```

and a few others to no avail.  There is not unique id or anything else that I can see.

**Sample file:**

```
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1018724/000144530513002495/amzn-20130930.xml
```

So how could I go about extracting this text?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that parsing the file above is very possible with Cheerio.

This works using Cheerio:

```
$('dei\\:CurrentFiscalYearEndDate').text().trim();
```

One must escape the special characters, **twice**, evidently.

Comment: Correct, colons need to be escaped, and that's a [standard CSS selector procedure](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/419).

Answer (score -1):

XBRL is XML and it cannot be treated as HTML DOM with libraries like cheerio. You will need an XML parser with Xpath support, like [xpath](https://npmjs.org/package/xpath),  [libxml](https://npmjs.org/package/libxml) or [o3-xml](https://npmjs.org/package/o3-xml)

Then you can get the value with an XPath expression like this:

```
/*/dei:DocumentType/text()
```

Comment: Wow, this answer is just wrong. I filed tickets with cheerio exactly for for these issues: [parsing XML](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/446), and [finding tags with colons in them](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/419).